# Can you call "express()" more than once in an ExpressJS application? (Or: what exactly is "express()" doing?)

Tags: node.js, express, keystonejs

I've been using Express for a while but suddenly I'm unsure about something pretty basic.

I'm trying to add custom middleware to a KeystoneJS application -- specifically I'm adding a JWT token endpoint to a TinyMCE custom field

The custom field is

```
export let Wysiwyg = {
  type: 'Wysiwyg',
  implementation: Text.implementation,
  views: {
    Controller: Text.views.Controller,
    Field: importView('./views/Field'),
    Filter: Text.views.Filter,
  },
  adapters: Text.adapters,
  prepareMiddleware,
};
```

and `prepareMiddleware` is

```
function prepareMiddleware() {
  const tinymcePath = dirname(require.resolve('tinymce'));
  const app = express();
  app.use(cors());

  app.use('/tinymce-assets', express.static(tinymcePath));
  app.post('/jwt', function (req, res) {
    // NOTE: Before you proceed with the TOKEN, verify your users' session or access.
    const payload = {
      sub: '123', // Unique user id string
      name: 'John Doe', // Full name of user

      // Optional custom user root path
      // 'https://claims.tiny.cloud/drive/root': '/johndoe',

      exp: Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) + (60 * 60) // 60 minutes expiration
    };

    try {
      const token = jwt.sign(payload, privateKey, { algorithm: 'RS256'});
      res.set('content-type', 'application/json');
      res.status(200);
      res.send(JSON.stringify({
        token: token
      }));
    } catch (e) {
      res.status(500);
      res.send(e.message);
    }
  });
  return app;
}
```

This is all called from a KeystoneJS app that has its own ExpressJS server running.  What exactly is the call to `express()` above doing?  The [ExpressJS API docs](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html) say

```
**express()**

Creates an Express application. The express() function is a top-level function exported by the express module.

var express = require('express')
var app = express()
```

I always understood this to be creating a new HTTP server.  Surely you don't want to do that twice in a single app unless you're serving on different ports (which I'm not trying to do)?

Similarly, the [KeystoneJS docs](https://www.keystonejs.com/guides/apps) say

> If you need to provide your own custom middleware for your system you
> can create a custom App and include it in your exported apps.

```
class CustomApp {
  prepareMiddleware({ keystone, dev, distDir }) {
    const middleware = express();
    // ...
    return middleware;
  }
}
```

Here, again, they're calling `express()`.

What exactly happens when you call`express()`?  It starts a new Express app, according to the docs, but I always thought this was equivalent to starting a new server.  Surely, I thought, you can't start two servers on the same port?

I am seeking to clear up some confusion -- I'm obviously not seeing the forest for the trees.

Comment: yes you can call express() more than once in one project

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`express()`](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#express) basically *just* creates a stack of middleware functions. It's not a server on its own.

Because it's just a stack of middleware, an Express app can be 'mounted' into another app. [An example is shown here](https://derickbailey.com/2016/02/17/using-express-sub-apps-to-keep-your-code-clean/) (edited for brevity):

```
var sub2 = express();
sub2.get("/", (req, res) => { res.json({}); });

var app = express();
app.use("/foo", sub2);
```

Defining and `use()`ing a new Express instance is really **no different from loading any other middleware stack**, such as `express.Router()`.

As for binding to ports, usually, you'll only call the [`listen()`](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#app.listen) helper function on the upper-most Express app instance. All this does is set up a basic HTTP server (so you don't have to) and registers your Express instance as the callback. It's little different from doing `http.createServer(options, myUpperMostExpressApp);`.